# Ruby 1.9.3 nil? undefined local variable or method. Is nil? broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been using `var.nil?` for a while, it's all over my code. Suddenly, I'm getting `undefined local variable or method` for the variable with `.nil?` after it.

What's going on? is `.nil?` broken? I even tried it on an IRB online to make sure it wasn't something in my environment. I should be able to type:

```
me.nil?
```

and that should come back as true if the variable hasn't been defined, that's the whole point, but I get `undefined local variable or method me for main:Object`

Maybe I got `nil?` wrong and have to use something like:

```
defined?(me) == nil
```

and `.nil?` can only be used with an existing object? This was not the way I understood it. The ruby docs even say this:

```
nil.nil?               -> true
<anything_else>.nil?   -> false
```

Going crazy here.

**More info**

I understand that I can do:

```
unless defined? me
 do something
```

But the equivalent of `if me.nil?` would only be:

```
if defined?(me) == nil?
```

right? There's no other way to do it?

Now I'm questioning not only my knowledge but my sanity :)

**Conclusion:**

Ok, so `.nil?` works for non-existing instance variables, it also works with non-existing hash or array keys, but it won't work with non-existing local variables. To me this is a huge mistake. You have to keep it in your mind that it works with almost everything except perhaps the most used item (local variable).

My conclusion is this has to do with the fact that a local variable can be confused for a method in Ruby, there is nothing in the syntax separating them (usage is different yes, but I mean in other languages you prepend a `$` or whatever to a variable and it can never be confused for a method).

Comment: Question downvoted? I wonder why. Surely I'm not the only one confused about this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are right and wrong both. nil? works for instance variables but not for local or class variables. So if you do

```
@me.nil? => true
```

Instance variables doesn't give an error because, by default they are assigned to nil.

but if you do

```
me.nil? => NameError
```

Comment: But not for local variables? What if they are defined previously? I mean something like, `me = 'test' or me = true and then me.nil? would result in false.` When you assign `me = nil and then me.nil? would give you true.` Isn't me a local variable here? The point here is the variable should be defined before the call. Sorry, If the questioning was a bit rude here.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, offcourse if its defined .nil? will work for them but my point is even if you not define instance variable you can run @me.nil? on that.

Comment: Ok, I get it now, may be I got it in the wrong sense when you answered. Now you cleared me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! This is what was throwing me off, it works for instance variables but not for local ones which seems... weird (to use an euphemism). My theory is that a local variable in Ruby can be easily confused with a method while an instance variable cannot be confused with anything else.

Comment: @kakubei Please check the edited answer of techvineet now. You can understand why it works for instance variables.

Comment: It will also work for hash and array keys. Of course, the hash has to be defined, but you can do `hash[:key].nil?` and it will return true or false depending on whether the key exists or not. So if it works for non-existing instance variables it **should** also work for local variables but doesn't (possibly due to the whole method thing).

Comment: It will also work for unitialized local variables. Try this: `if false then foo = 42 end; foo.nil? # => true`. You just have to *tell* Ruby that it is, in fact, a variable and not a method which you do by having it *parse* but not necessarily *execute* an assignment expression.

Comment: @JörgWMittag in your example you are setting the foo variable to 42 if false. And I'd like to use `foo.nil?` without having to set anything. I might as well use `defined?(foo) == nil`.

Comment: Well, if you want to call a method on an object, then you need to have an object. You cannot call a method on a variable, because variables aren't objects. Uninitialized variables evaluate to `nil`, so you *do* have an object to call the method on, but you need to tell Ruby *somehow* that what you have is a variable and not a method call. And you do that by having Ruby parse an assignment. Note: in my example, I am *not* setting `foo` to anything. The assignment is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Thats obvious. If it is a variable or method then that should be defined previously.

```
'me'.nil? -> false. This is correct as the string 'me' is not nil.
```

In the above example 'me' acts as a self object of String class.

```
 Now, me.nil? without defining the variable or method me will definitely throw an error.
```

In the above one the me object is not defined anywhere.

Make sure that the code han't been modified by someone else recently, like the definition of the var (variable or method) removed or something else.

Yes, nil can only be used with an existing object. When a string is directly used, the self object is utilised. If you want to use a variable then that should definitely be assigned to something.

Comment: See, my understanding was that you could use `.nil?` for non-existent objects. I was, apparently, wrong, but it made perfect sense to me, it seemed like a very elegant way to test for a variable's existence. In general I care more whether an existing variable is empty than nil. `defined?(me) == nil` is so ugly. Is there no other way when you need an assertion and don't want to use `unless`?

Comment: Sorry couldn't get this part. 'Is there no other way when you need an assertion and don't want to use `unless?`' can you quote an example of what actually you need, as an edit to the question?

Comment: @kakubei If variables existence could be checked via `nil`, then how would you test whether a variable contains `nil` ?

Comment: I'd say it's bad coding practice to explicitly expect variables to be undefined. You should always have some kind of default value (even if that 'value' is nil), e.g.: `my_flag = false; if condition { my_flag = true }`. Most IDEs should warn about such code pieces if the variables are only defined if the condition is met (without the preceding default definition).

Comment: Wondering why I got one downvote for this answer. Actually one downvote and one upvote totalled to zero.